# control linux terminal using c++ program

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal

I can open a program in terminal using:

```
stringstream s;
s<<"./~/rajat/app -parameter";
system(s.str().c_str());
```

My app keeps on running in a terminal , what I want to do is shut down this app from inside the same program and open it again using new parameters. How to do this?

Comment: You will need to provide some means to control `app` from outside, either via a pipe (or some other IPC mechanism) or make it respond to a signal (eg. SIGHUP) and your controlling application can use those means to terminate it and then re-execute it as required.

Comment: could you please tell me the reason for negative voting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using `system`. From (BSD) `man 3 system`:

> The calling process *waits* for the shell to finish executing the command, ignoring SIGINT and SIGQUIT, and blocking SIGCHLD.

So your app will block until the completion or termination of the launched program.

You can get the behavior that you want by instead launching your program using `fork`/`exec` - man pages [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork), and [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec). This is what `system` is doing under the hood. You'll launch the sub-process and maintain control in your app.

Using `fork`, you'll get a process id for your launched process, and using that you can e.g. terminate the program using `kill` - man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) - and re-launch the program.

Look around for `fork`/`exec` examples, there are probably more than a few on this site.

Comment: You get half the requested behaviour, but the other half is easy enough to implement. `fork()` returns a process ID, and then use `kill(pid, signal)` to terminate the spawned process when required.

Answer (score 2):

`system()` only lets you start up another process and get back its exit code. You don't get any control over that other process's lifecycle.

If you want to start other processes and control them, you need to use other methods. The classic way would be to `fork()` your own process into two and `exec()` the other process in the child. The parent would then have the child's PID from the `fork()` call, and could then send suitable signals to the child from the parent when you want to terminate it.

This is a bit messy (especially once you start having to handle SIGHUP and cleaning up zombie processes), but I'm not aware of a standard or Boost library which does the nasty bits for you. You should probably check before you start writing this manually though.

If you do go with `fork()`, there are plenty of guides online which will take you through the specifics and the idioms which have built up around it over the decades.